# Pure config enum

Tags: scala, pureconfig

Pure config can't pars capital letters in conf

```
  sealed trait Occupation extends Product with Serializable


  object Occupation {
    case class Employed(job: String) extends Occupation

    object Employed {
      implicit val employedReader = deriveReader[Employed]
    }

    case object Unemployed extends Occupation {
      implicit val unemployedReader = deriveReader[Unemployed.type]
    }

    case object Student extends Occupation {
      implicit val studentReader = deriveReader[Student.type]
    }

    implicit val occupationReader = deriveReader[Occupation]
  }

  case class WorkingPerson(name: String, surname: String, occupation: Occupation)

  val res = ConfigSource.string("{ name: Isaac, surname: Newton, occupation.type: student }").load[WorkingPerson]
```

It works, but I need enum value like 'StudenT' and if I do so I got
"ConvertFailure(UnexpectedValueForFieldCoproductHint(Unquoted("student"))"

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I need to parse string to the exactly "StudenT" enum name

Comment: Example https://scastie.scala-lang.org/GYEv2yiNStGdnjSaVZghXg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change [how the field is being read](https://pureconfig.github.io/docs/overriding-behavior-for-sealed-families.html) you need to provide a `hint`.

> For sealed families, PureConfig provides a way to customize the conversion without replacing the default `ConfigReader`. By putting in scope an instance of `CoproductHint` for that sealed family, we can customize how the disambiguation is made. For example, if `type` clashes with one of the fields of a case class option, we can use another field.
>
> ```scala
> import pureconfig.generic.FieldCoproductHint
> implicit val animalConfHint = new FieldCoproductHint[AnimalConf]("kind")
> ```
>
> ---
>
> `FieldCoproductHint` can also be adapted to write class names in a different way. First, define a new `FieldCoproductHint` in implicit scope:
>
> ```scala
> implicit val animalConfHint = new FieldCoproductHint[AnimalConf]("type") {
>   override def fieldValue(name: String) = name.dropRight("Conf".length)
> }
> ```

In this case, adding `FieldCoproductHint[Occupation]` is what you need to do

```scala
implicit val occupationConfHint = new FieldCoproductHint[Occupation]("type") {
  override def fieldValue(name: String) = name
}
```

I created a [working example in scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/iclDAwnmSrGIwOamyaYDCQ)

---

Do you really need to use the [Semi-Automatic derivation](https://pureconfig.github.io/docs/non-automatic-derivation.html#semi-automatic-for-sealed-families)? You can get the same result just using the [automatic](https://pureconfig.github.io/docs/non-automatic-derivation.html#automatic) one.

Here is the [working example in scatsie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/oNqn9qPoSAWBKzWLnQbqkg)

- `build.sbt`

```scala
libraryDependencies += "com.github.pureconfig" %% "pureconfig" % "0.14.0"
```

- `main.scala`

```scala
import pureconfig._
import pureconfig.generic.FieldCoproductHint
import pureconfig.generic.auto._

sealed trait Occupation extends Product with Serializable

implicit val occupationConfHint = new FieldCoproductHint[Occupation]("type") {
  override def fieldValue(name: String) = name
}

object Occupation {
  case class Employed(job: String) extends Occupation
  case object Unemployed extends Occupation
  case object StudenT extends Occupation
}

case class WorkingPerson(name: String, surname: String, occupation: Occupation)

val res = ConfigSource.string("{ name: Isaac, surname: Newton, occupation.type: StudenT }").load[WorkingPerson]
println(res)
```

Comment: Can I provide a hint for a case insensitive occupation.type?

Comment: take a look at [Field mappings](https://pureconfig.github.io/docs/overriding-behavior-for-case-classes.html#field-mappings). There are default `naming conventions` such as `CamelCase`, `PascalCase`, `KebabCase`, etc. If none of them are useful, you would need to create your own [NamingConvention](https://github.com/pureconfig/pureconfig/blob/ec6b0dd4e5e10fb37fc92f0e96aafa47bdba4601/core/src/main/scala/pureconfig/NamingConvention.scala#L3)

Comment: I found work appoach https://scastie.scala-lang.org/f0jlrDfvQmms1uxfidFvtQ